# How solve app:mergeDexRelease Failed issue?

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, release

**Logs**
Run gradle/gradle-build-action@v2.2.2
Gradle User Home already exists: will not restore from cache.
/home/runner/work/File-Explorer/File-Explorer/gradlew assembleRelease
Welcome to Gradle 7.5!
Here are the highlights of this release:

- Support for Java 18
- Support for building with Groovy 4
- Much more responsive continuous builds
- Improved diagnostics for dependency resolution
  For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/release-notes.html
  Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
  WARNING:We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 33
  This Android Gradle plugin (7.2.1) was tested up to compileSdk = 32
  This warning can be suppressed by adding
  android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33
  to this project's gradle.properties
  The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to
  use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 33

> Task :build-logic:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :build-logic:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :kotlinc:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :kotlinc:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :kotlinc:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :build-logic:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :build-logic:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :build-logic:mergeReleaseNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :build-logic:stripReleaseDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :kotlinc:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :build-logic:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :build-logic:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars
> Task :build-logic:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :build-logic:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :build-logic:generateReleaseResources
> Task :build-logic:packageReleaseResources
> Task :build-logic:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :kotlinc:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :kotlinc:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :kotlinc:generateReleaseResources
> Task :kotlinc:packageReleaseResources
> Task :kotlinc:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :build-logic:processReleaseManifest
> Task :kotlinc:processReleaseManifest
> Task :kotlinc:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :kotlinc:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :build-logic:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :build-logic:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :build-logic:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :build-logic:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :build-logic:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :build-logic:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :build-logic:prepareLintJarForPublish
> Task :build-logic:prepareReleaseArtProfile
> Task :kotlinc:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :build-logic:processReleaseJavaRes
> Task :build-logic:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :build-logic:mergeReleaseJavaResource
> Task :build-logic:writeReleaseAarMetadata
> Task :kotlinc:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :kotlinc:mergeReleaseNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :kotlinc:stripReleaseDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :kotlinc:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars
> Task :kotlinc:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :kotlinc:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :kotlinc:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :kotlinc:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :kotlinc:prepareLintJarForPublish
> Task :kotlinc:prepareReleaseArtProfile
> Task :kotlinc:processReleaseJavaRes
> Task :kotlinc:writeReleaseAarMetadata
> Task :app:buildKotlinToolingMetadata
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :app:checkReleaseAarMetadata
> Task :app:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :app:generateReleaseResources
> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources
> Task :app:mapReleaseSourceSetPaths
> Task :app:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :build-logic:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :kotlinc:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :app:processReleaseMainManifest
> Task :app:processReleaseManifest
> Task :app:processReleaseManifestForPackage
> Task :build-logic:compileReleaseLibraryResources
> Task :kotlinc:compileReleaseLibraryResources
> Task :app:processReleaseResources
> Task :app:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :app:extractProguardFiles
> Task :build-logic:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :build-logic:writeReleaseLintModelMetadata
> Task :kotlinc:writeReleaseLintModelMetadata
> Task :app:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :build-logic:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :kotlinc:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :app:mergeReleaseNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:stripReleaseDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:extractReleaseNativeSymbolTables NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses
> Task :kotlinc:compileReleaseKotlin
> w: /home/runner/work/File-Explorer/File-Explorer/kotlinc/src/main/java/org/jetbrains/kotlin/cli/jvm/plugins/ServiceLoaderLite.kt: (52, 13): Unsafe use of a nullable receiver of type MutableList
> w: /home/runner/work/File-Explorer/File-Explorer/kotlinc/src/main/java/org/jetbrains/kotlin/cli/jvm/plugins/ServiceLoaderLite.kt: (75, 43): 'toLowerCase(): String' is deprecated. Use lowercase() instead.
> w: /home/runner/work/File-Explorer/File-Explorer/kotlinc/src/main/java/org/jetbrains/kotlin/utils/PathUtil.kt: (132, 24): Unsafe use of a nullable receiver of type File?
> w: /home/runner/work/File-Explorer/File-Explorer/kotlinc/src/main/java/org/jetbrains/kotlin/utils/PathUtil.kt: (132, 24): Type mismatch: inferred type is File? but File was expected
> w: /home/runner/work/File-Explorer/File-Explorer/kotlinc/src/main/java/org/jetbrains/kotlin/utils/PathUtil.kt: (145, 34): Unsafe use of a nullable receiver of type File?
> w: /home/runner/work/File-Explorer/File-Explorer/kotlinc/src/main/java/org/jetbrains/kotlin/utils/PathUtil.kt: (165, 35): Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected
> Task :app:desugarReleaseFileDependencies
> Task :kotlinc:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
> Task :kotlinc:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease
> Task :build-logic:extractReleaseAnnotations
> Task :build-logic:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
> Task :build-logic:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles
> Task :build-logic:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles
> Task :build-logic:syncReleaseLibJars
> Task :build-logic:bundleReleaseLocalLintAar
> Task :kotlinc:extractReleaseAnnotations
> Task :kotlinc:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles
> Task :kotlinc:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles
> Task :build-logic:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease
> Task :app:compileReleaseKotlin NO-SOURCE
> Task :kotlinc:mergeReleaseJavaResource
> Task :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Note: [1] Wrote GeneratedAppGlideModule with: []
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> Task :kotlinc:syncReleaseLibJars
> Task :kotlinc:bundleReleaseLocalLintAar
> Task :kotlinc:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :kotlinc:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease
> Task :kotlinc:createFullJarRelease
> Task :build-logic:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease
> Task :app:mergeExtDexRelease
> Task :build-logic:createFullJarRelease
> Task :build-logic:bundleLibRuntimeToDirRelease
> Task :app:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease
> Task :app:lintVitalReportRelease
> Task :app:lintVitalRelease
> Task :kotlinc:bundleLibRuntimeToDirRelease
> Task :app:dexBuilderRelease
> Task :app:mergeReleaseArtProfile
> Task :app:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :app:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :app:compressReleaseAssets
> Task :app:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseJavaResource
> Task :app:optimizeReleaseResources
> Task :app:collectReleaseDependencies
> Task :app:sdkReleaseDependencyData
> Task :app:writeReleaseAppMetadata
> Task :app:writeReleaseSigningConfigVersions
> Task :build-logic:bundleReleaseAar
> Task :build-logic:mergeReleaseResources
> Task :build-logic:mapReleaseSourceSetPaths
> Task :build-logic:verifyReleaseResources
> Task :build-logic:assembleRelease
> Task :kotlinc:bundleReleaseAar
> Task :kotlinc:mergeReleaseResources
> Task :kotlinc:mapReleaseSourceSetPaths
> Task :kotlinc:verifyReleaseResources
> Task :kotlinc:assembleRelease
> Task :app:mergeDexRelease FAILED
> ERROR:/home/runner/work/File-Explorer/File-Explorer/build-logic/build/.transforms/63709c9a363d9d7c070fd985789aef5f/transformed/release/org/w3c/dom/html/HTMLDOMImplementation.dex: D8: Type org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLDOMImplementation is defined multiple times: /home/runner/work/File-Explorer/File-Explorer/build-logic/build/.transforms/63709c9a363d9d7c070fd985789aef5f/transformed/release/org/w3c/dom/html/HTMLDOMImplementation.dex, /home/runner/work/File-Explorer/File-Explorer/app/build/intermediates/external_libs_dex/release/mergeExtDexRelease/classes7.dex
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
> Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
> Type org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLDOMImplementation is defined multiple times: /home/runner/work/File-Explorer/File-Explorer/build-logic/build/.transforms/63709c9a363d9d7c070fd985789aef5f/transformed/release/org/w3c/dom/html/HTMLDOMImplementation.dex, /home/runner/work/File-Explorer/File-Explorer/app/build/intermediates/external_libs_dex/release/mergeExtDexRelease/classes7.dex
> at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:151)
> at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:138)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction.merge(DexMergingTask.kt:859)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction.run(DexMergingTask.kt:805)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.ProfileAwareWorkAction.execute(ProfileAwareWorkAction.kt:74)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
> at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
> at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:205)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)
> at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:114)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: /home/runner/work/File-Explorer/File-Explorer/build-logic/build/.transforms/63709c9a363d9d7c070fd985789aef5f/transformed/release/org/w3c/dom/html/HTMLDOMImplementation.dex
> at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_3.2.60.java:0)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.bi.a(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:68)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.bi.a(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:28)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.bi.a(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:27)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.bi.b(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:3)
> at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:11)
> at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:136)
> ... 38 more
> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.internal.a: Type org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLDOMImplementation is defined multiple times: /home/runner/work/File-Explorer/File-Explorer/build-logic/build/.transforms/63709c9a363d9d7c070fd985789aef5f/transformed/release/org/w3c/dom/html/HTMLDOMImplementation.dex, /home/runner/work/File-Explorer/File-Explorer/app/build/intermediates/external_libs_dex/release/mergeExtDexRelease/classes7.dex
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.uQ.a(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:14)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.uQ.a(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:22)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.yK.b(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:7)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.yK.a(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:23)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.yK.a(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:10)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.merge(ConcurrentHashMap.java:2056)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.yK.a(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:6)
> at com.android.tools.r8.graph.A2$a.e(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:4)
> at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.a(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:105)
> at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.a(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:28)
> at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:26)
> at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:593)
> at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:1)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.bi.a(R8_3.2.60_61a204e00a4460bee78ec2913234dc5e1a3a501d9754e757835d117b7e302ba3:24)
> ... 41 more
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexRelease'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate
> There was a failure while executing work items
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
> > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
> Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
> Type org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLDOMImplementation is defined multiple times: /home/runner/work/File-Explorer/File-Explorer/build-logic/build/.transforms/63709c9a363d9d7c070fd985789aef5f/transformed/release/org/w3c/dom/html/HTMLDOMImplementation.dex, /home/runner/work/File-Explorer/File-Explorer/app/build/intermediates/external_libs_dex/release/mergeExtDexRelease/classes7.dex

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 4m 13s
  Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
  You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
  See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
  105 actionable tasks: 105 executed
  Error: Gradle build failed: see console output for details
  0s
  1s
  0s
  0s
  0s